# Knative Service can't be triggered by Knative Broker & Trigger

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, knative, knative-serving, knative-eventing

I am testing Knative in GKE and Here is what I would like to do:

[image]

However, I got the following error in logs of "default-broker-filter" :

```
caller: "http/transport.go:508"   
error: "Post http://helloworld-python.knative-samples.svc.cluster.local: dial tcp: lookup helloworld-python.knative-samples.svc.cluster.local on 10.0.0.10:53: no such host"   
level: "warn"   
logger: "fallback"   
msg: "got an error from receiver fn"
```

I use [this official tutorial](https://knative.dev/docs/install/knative-with-gke/) to install Knative with the following command:

```
kubectl apply --selector knative.dev/crd-install=true \
--filename https://github.com/knative/serving/releases/download/v0.12.0/serving.yaml \
--filename https://github.com/knative/eventing/releases/download/v0.12.0/eventing.yaml \
--filename https://github.com/knative/serving/releases/download/v0.12.0/monitoring.yaml

kubectl apply --filename https://github.com/knative/serving/releases/download/v0.12.0/serving.yaml \
--filename https://github.com/knative/eventing/releases/download/v0.12.0/eventing.yaml \
--filename https://github.com/knative/serving/releases/download/v0.12.0/monitoring.yaml
```

Here is my yaml template I used to install my trigger and my service hello world in python:

```
# Namespace for sample application with eventing enabled
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: knative-samples
  labels:
    knative-eventing-injection: enabled
---
apiVersion: serving.knative.dev/v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: helloworld-python
  namespace: knative-samples
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: gcr.io/knative-samples/helloworld-python
          env:
            - name: TARGET
              value: "Python Sample v1"

---
# Knative Eventing Trigger to trigger the helloworld-go service
apiVersion: eventing.knative.dev/v1alpha1
kind: Trigger
metadata:
  name: my-service-trigger
  namespace: knative-samples
spec:
  broker: default
  filter:
    attributes:
      type: dev.knative.samples.helloworld
  subscriber:
    ref:
      apiVersion: serving.knative.dev/v1
      kind: Service
      name: helloworld-python
```

Then I create a pod to execute my curl command:

```
kubectl --namespace knative-samples run curl --image=radial/busyboxplus:curl -it

curl -v "default-broker.knative-samples.svc.cluster.local" \
  -X POST \
  -H "Ce-Id: 536808d3-88be-4077-9d7a-a3f162705f79" \
  -H "Ce-specversion: 0.3" \
  -H "Ce-Type: dev.knative.samples.helloworld" \
  -H "Ce-Source: dev.knative.samples/helloworldsource" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d '{"msg":"Hello World from the curl pod."}'
```

Can you tell me what it is wrong because I spent all my week-end without finding any clue ?

Thanks,

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes are you running on GKE?

Comment: This version 1.14.10-gke.17

Answer (score 1):

Do you have cluster local gateway enabled? If not then this might be the reason why it isn't working. Details at the following link:

https://knative.dev/docs/install/installing-istio/

Answer (score 0):

Your application is accepting `GET` requests only, as you can see here - https://github.com/knative/docs/blob/master/docs/serving/samples/hello-world/helloworld-python/app.py

As you can see in the `cloudevents` spec - https://github.com/cloudevents/spec/blob/master/http-webhook.md#21-delivery-request

> The HTTP method for the delivery request MUST be POST.

You have to use `POST` method to trigger your service.

If you want to fix it, you have two simple choices:

1. You can change the image of the service to `event_display` (`gcr.io/knative-releases/github.com/knative/eventing-sources/cmd/event_display`)
2. You can change the code of your application, and change [L7](https://github.com/knative/docs/blob/master/docs/serving/samples/hello-world/helloworld-python/app.py#L7) from `@app.route('/')` to `@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])`